# Immediate flag in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a clients that uses API. The API sends messeges to rabbitmq. Rabbitmq to workers.

I ought to reply to clients if somethings went wrong - message wasn't routed to a certain queue and wasn't obtained for performing at this time ( full confirmation )
A task who is started after 5-10 seconds does not make sense.

Appropriately, I must use mandatory and immediate flags.
I can't increase counts of workers, I can't run workers on another servers. It's a demand.

So, as I could find the immediate flag hadn't been supporting since rabbitmq v.3.0x
The developers of rabbitmq suggests to use TTL=0 for a queue instead but then I will not be able to check status of message.

Whether any opportunity to change that behavior? Please, share your experience how you solved problems like this.

Thank you.

Comment: So you want to get result from your worker for published message immediately?

Comment: Right! But rabbitmq doesn't support it. http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/11/19/breaking-things-with-rabbitmq-3-0/ Removal of "immediate" flag.  I'm looking for a solution or analog for rabbitmq

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not sure, but after reading your original question in Russian, it might be that using both publisher and consumer confirms may be what you want. See last three paragraphs in this answer.*

As you want to get message result for published message from your worker, it looks like RPC pattern is what you want. See [RabbitMQ RPC tuttorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html). Pick a programming language section there you most comfortable with, overall concept is the same. You may also find [Direct reply-to](https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html) useful.

It's not the same as `immediate` flag functionality, but in case all your publishers operate with `immediate` scenario, it might be that AMQP protocol is not the best choice for such kind of task. Immediate mean "deliver this message right now or burn in hell" and it might be a situation when you publish more than you can process. In such cases RPC + response timeout may be a good choice on application side (e.g. socket timeout). But it doesn't work well for non-idempotent RPC calls while message still be processed, so you may want to use [per-queue or per-message TTL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) (or set [queue length limit](https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html)). In case message will be [dead-lettered](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html), you may get it there (in case you need that for some reason).

**TL;DR**

As to "something" can go wrong, it can go so on different levels which we for simplicity define as:

- before RabbitMQ, like sending application failure and network problems;
- inside RabbitMQ, say, missed destination queue, message timeout, queue length limit, some hard and unexpected internal error;
- after RabbitMQ, in most cases - messages processing application error or some third-party services like data persistence or caching layer outage.

Some errors like network outage or hardware error are a bit epic and are not a subject of this q/a.

Typical scenario for guaranteed message delivery is to use [publisher confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) or transactions (which are slower). After you got a confirm it mean that RabbitMQ got your message and if it has route - placed in a queue. If not it is dropped OR if `mandatory` flag set returned with `basic.return` method.

For consumers it's similar - after `basic.consumer`/`basic.get`, client ack'ed message it considered received and removed from queue.

So when you use confirms on both ends, you are protected from message loss (we'll not run into a situation that there might be some bug in RabbitMQ itself).

Comment: If you want, I will post in Russian.

Comment: No need for that, I'm fine with both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Bogdan, thank you for your reply.
Seems, I expressed my thought enough clearly.

Scheme may looks like this. Each component of system must do what it must do :)
The an idea is make every component more simple.

[image]

**How to task is performed.**
Clients goes to HTTP-API with requests and must obtain a respones like this:

- Positive - it have put to queue
- Negative - response with error and a reason

When I was talking about confirmation I meant that I must to know that a message is delivered ( there are no free workers - rabbitmq can remove a message ), a client must be notified.
A sent message couldn't be delivered to certain queue, a client must be notified.

**How to a message is handled.**

- Messages is sent for performing.
- Status of perfoming is written into HeartBeat

**Status.**

- Clients obtain status from HeartBeat by itself and then decide that
  it's have to do.

I'm not sure, that RPC may be useful for us i.e. RPC means that clients must to wait response from server. Tasks may works a long time. Excess bound between clients and servers, additional logic on client-side.

Limited size of queue maybe not useful too. 
Possible situation when a size of queue maybe greater than counts of workers. ( problem in configuration or defined settings ).
Then an idea with 5-10 seconds doesn't make sense.

TTL doesn't usefull because of:

> Setting the TTL to 0 causes messages to be expired upon reaching a
>   queue unless they can be delivered to a consumer immediately. Thus
>   this provides an alternative to basic.publish's immediate flag, which
>   the RabbitMQ server does not support. Unlike that flag, no
>   basic.returns are issued, and if a dead letter exchange is set then
>   messages will be dead-lettered.

direct reply-to :

> The RPC server will then see a reply-to property with a generated
>   name. It should publish to the default exchange ("") with the routing
>   key set to this value (i.e. just as if it were sending to a reply
>   queue as usual). The message will then be sent straight to the client
>   consumer.

Then I will not be able to route messages.

So, I'm sorry. I may flounder in terms i.e. I'm new in AMQP and rabbitmq.

Comment: In case confirms doesn't work for you, then I guess I still don't get what you want to achieve, sorry.